# Validate AzureAD token in Web Api

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-active-directory

I have a dotnet core Web Api project which is registered within Azure AD. When I want to access it I request a token from Azrue AD and with that token I can access my API. This works without problems. The way I have configure my API is:

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
   .AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd",options));
```

What I would like to do then is to validate the token for each request that is accessing my API. I want to know who requested the token (clientID) and other information. Is that possible or am I taking the wrong approach?

/christoph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your on the right track.

The Azure AD token will contain claims, so from that you can determine who is requesting access.

More information here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens

Samples here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code

You can also use https://jwt.io/ to crack open a JWT token, to inspect what claims are in there.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Inside the MS documentation page there was a link to some samples. In one of those I found a solution I could use. Also thanks for the link to the JWT site!

Comment: Great! I'll add a samples link to the answer for others.